# Qual a forma correta, Irei ver-te" ou "Irei te ver"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, português-europeu, verbos

Qual a forma correta?

"Irei ver-te" ou "Irei te ver" ?

Pode ser das duas maneiras ?

Comment: ClMend, uma pergunta ou é *especificamente* sobre português europeu (pt-PT) ou sobre português brasileiro (pt-BR). Não pode ser especificamente sobre uma se é sobre a outra... e é para isso que servem essas duas tags: [tag:português-europeu] e [tag:português-brasileiro]. Não deves usar as duas tags na mesma pergunta.

Comment: Eis uma solução para os teus problemas: https://www.todamateria.com.br/colocacao-pronominal. Com uma nota: no Brasil, é mais comum "haviam te dito" em vez de "haviam-te dito, ao menos que fosse haver mudança no verbo se fosse assim, como "haviam-no dito" em vez de "haviam o dito" e "tê-lo feito é crime" em vez de "ter o feito é crime".

Comment: Em caso de dúvida, diga então "ver-te-ei". :-)

Comment: Acho que usar os dois tags significa que a pessoa quer saber as duas possibilidades.

Comment: no português falado e não formal, no Brasil se usa mais a **próclise** ou seja, o pronome vem antes do verbo "Irei te ver", já em Portugal o costume é usar a **ênclise**, ou seja, o pronome vem após o verbo "Irei ver-te". Então as duas formas são corretas. **Porém**, na linguagem formal escrita, existem regras para o bom uso, e isso vale tanto para o português falado no Brasil como em Portugal (sempre há as famosas regras :)) , alguns exemplos aqui: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,
Sou nativo brasileiro e espero poder te ajudar com minha resposta.

**Resumidamente, as duas formas estão corretas, porém a mais utilizada no Brasil é "irei te ver".**

No Brasil, palavras com hífen são raramente usadas na pronúncia, como por exemplo "beijar-te", "cala-te", "abraçar-te". Ao invés disso, normalmente invertemos a ordem e tiramos o hífen, como "te beijar", "se cale", "te abraçar".

As duas formas estão corretas, mas a mais utilizada no Brasil é sem o hífen.